# removing html tags from string

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I am trying to remove the HTML tags from a string. Right now I am able to remove the complete HTML tags like for example `<div class="test">dadsasdsad</div>` gives me the output `dadsasdsad`.

But I'm unable to remove partial tags like `class="test">dadsasdsad</div>`  or `testing<div class=`

The regular expression that Ive used is

```
strippedText[i] = fragments[i]
                   .replace(/<(?:.|\n)*?>/gm, '')
                   .replace(replaceAT, '<span style=font-weight:800>')
                   .replace(replaceET, '</span>');
```

Here `fragments[i]` contains the  input `<div class="test">dadsasdsad</div>`;

Comment: Is this javascript within a webpage? And the HTML is from the page itself? In that case, using the DOM functions is better; that's what they're there for. `text = thediv.firstChild.nodeValue`

Comment: There are many many SO questions about cleaning/fetching HTML using regex. The answer is always "don't use regex for that".

Comment: How would you distinguish "partial tag" from regular text?

Comment: Its from the website itself.. I ve created the condition when it occurence like <.*>, I wanna remove the others too like ^.><.$

Comment: Since the elements already *exist*,  use DOM manipulation to extract the text. Clone the nodes beforehand if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

```
strippedText[i] = fragments[i]
// full tags
.replace(/<[^>]+>/gm, '')
// partial tags
.replace(/^[^>]+>/gm, '')
.replace(/<[^>]+$/gm, '');
```

Note that ^ has different meanings: "not" within brackets, "start" outside brackets.

/gm should not be necessary for partial tags, but I left them as I don't know your context and how you're getting partial tags.

Answer (score 0):

Using `javascript` you can do this:

```
function removeHTMLTags(htmlString) {
    if(!htmlString) { return; }
    var mydiv = document.createElement("div");
    mydiv.innerHTML = htmlString;
    return mydiv.textContent || mydiv.innerText || '';
}
```

<sub>[[Source]](http://geekswithblogs.net/aghausman/archive/2008/10/30/how-to-remove-html-tags-from-a-string-in-javascript.aspx)</sub>

Comment: You can also do: `return mydiv.textContent || mydiv.innerText || '';`.

Comment: And you want to, you don't want to feature detect one thing (`document.all`) and then rely on something else (`innerText`).

Comment: any one knows hw to use the starts with and ends with $^ method... that was my question..

Answer (score 0):

my **simple** JavaScript library has a function called "strip_tags()" which does the long work for you.

Just say that you have a sentence loaded with HTML formatting tags, and you want to remove them, simply do it like this:

```
strip_tags("<p>This <em>sentence</em> contains <strong>a lot</strong> of tags!</p>");
```

This will output "This sentence contains a lot of tags!" (tested on the documentation website).

To read more about this function, please read the documentation at http://docs.funcjs.webege.com/strip_tags().html and if possible, leave feedback through the Feedback Form on the website.

Hope this helps you and anyone else with the same problem! :)